# What's the name of the board game about sailing between islands?

Tags: identify-this-game

I recently played a board game but forgot the name of it.  Can someone please tell me the title?

- You compete with other players to travel to other islands.
- During your turn, you can place boats in beach spots.
- When all the available beach slots are filled, you and the other players on that specific beach travel in a direction out from that beach.
- If there's nothing immediately adjacent to your beach, you flip a mystery tile to determine if it's another island or sea.
- If it's sea, there's a point cost system for the route you're on requiring a minimum number of different player colors.
- You collect points at the end of the game based on how many islands you're on (each island has a different point).
- I think the game title starts with a "T".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tongiaki, perhaps?  Description and image à la [BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9028/tongiaki):

> This game uses a unique tile design never seen in any other game (hexes with wavy edges), and is easy to explain and easy to enjoy. Players all begin on the island of Tonga, and immediate overcrowding forces players to search out other islands to populate. For each expedition that leaves, a new tile is placed, revealing either an island, or a "water path" that may or may not have a number from 2-4, indicating that many different players (not number of boats) must make up that expedition for it to survive the voyage (draw and place an additional tile). In this way, the game encourages both cooperative and competitive play at the same time.

[image: Sample of gameplay]